# Landscape table going off the page in elsarticle

Tags: tables, texstudio, landscape, elsarticle

I have a big table, which means i need to change to landscape orientation in an elsarticle document. The problem i have is the table goes off the page and I am not sure how to fix this.

MWE below:

```
\documentclass[final,10p,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=180mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}


\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table*}
    \caption[Caption.]{Caption.}
    \label{label}
    \begin{tabular}{ p{0.082\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} } \toprule
        & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Something}         &   ~   \\
        Something                   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Something(2)}                  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Something(1)}              & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Something (0)}             & Something         \\ 
        & Some & Some & Some                            & Some & Some & Some                        & Some & Some & Some                        &               \\ \midrule
        Something (2)                           & \textbf{data (data\%)} & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                    & data (data\%) & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                         & data  (data\%) & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                            & data          \\ \hdashline
        Something (2)                           & \textbf{data (data\%)} & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                    & data (data\%) & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                         & data  (data\%) & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                            & data          \\ \hdashline
        Something (2)                           & \textbf{data (data\%)} & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                    & data (data\%) & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                         & data  (data\%) & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                            & data          \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `\begin{landscape}` is messing with page layout. See that the page number is misplaced.

I'd rotate the table manually with a `minipage` inside a `rotatebox`. Needed to use `\centering` to put the table in the middle of the page.

Check if this is enough for your problem:

```
\documentclass[final,10p,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=180mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}


\begin{document}


\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \rotatebox{90}{
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \caption[Caption.]{Caption.}
    \label{label}

    \begin{tabular}{ p{0.082\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} } \toprule
        & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Something}         &   ~   \\
        Something                   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Something(2)}                  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Something(1)}              & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Something (0)}             & Something         \\ 
        & Some & Some & Some                            & Some & Some & Some                        & Some & Some & Some                        &               \\ \midrule
        Something (2)                           & \textbf{data (data\%)} & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                    & data (data\%) & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                         & data  (data\%) & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                            & data          \\ \hdashline
        Something (2)                           & \textbf{data (data\%)} & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                    & data (data\%) & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                         & data  (data\%) & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                            & data          \\ \hdashline
        Something (2)                           & \textbf{data (data\%)} & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                    & data (data\%) & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                         & data  (data\%) & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                            & data          \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `table` in place of `table*`:

```
\documentclass[final,10p,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=180mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}

\begin{document}
 
 \begin{landscape}
  \begin{table}
   \centering
   \caption[Caption.]{Caption.}
   \label{label}
   \begin{tabular}{ p{0.082\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} p{0.08\textwidth} } \toprule
    & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Something}         &   ~   \\
    Something                   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Something(2)}                  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Something(1)}              & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Something (0)}             & Something         \\ 
    & Some & Some & Some                            & Some & Some & Some                        & Some & Some & Some                        &               \\ \midrule
    Something (2)                           & \textbf{data (data\%)} & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                    & data (data\%) & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                         & data  (data\%) & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                            & data          \\ \hdashline
    Something (2)                           & \textbf{data (data\%)} & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                    & data (data\%) & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                         & data  (data\%) & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                            & data          \\ \hdashline
    Something (2)                           & \textbf{data (data\%)} & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                    & data (data\%) & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                         & data  (data\%) & data (data\%) & data (data\%)                            & data          \\
    \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
 \end{landscape}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]